# MySQL using IF to test if count of items in one table is equal to a value in a Column of another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. tbl_Assessment and tbl_questionnaires related by field named assessmentID. I am trying to use a single query to test if count of questionnaires in tbl_questionnaires is equal to a previously set number of items in the tbl_Assessment.what I wanna do is to return a TRUE or FALSE IF the condition is met or not.

The tables are somewhat like this:

#### tbl_Assessment

- assessmentID: 2016030098
- noOfitems: 25

#### tbl_questionnaires

- qID
- assessmentID: 2016030098
- qDescription

Answer (score 1):

u can try this

```
select count(a.*) from tbl_Assessment inner join tbl_questionnaires b on a.assessmentID=b.assessmentID where a.assessmentID=2016030098;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM tbl_questionnaires WHERE ta.assessmentID = 2016030098) = ta.noOfitems AS `EqualStatus`
FROM tbl_Assessment ta
```